# How to plot frequency response for a transfer function of a band-pass filter in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, syntax-error, filtering

i want write a script to plot a graph for the transfer function [H(f)] for a band pass filter, |H(f)| against frequency and the phase of H(f) (degrees) against frequency, im very new to matlab so the syntax is not 100%, im getting confused because everything is auto formatted in matrix form.
below is my script:

```
% RCL circuit: band-pass filter
R=55590; L=0.9571; C=48.811*10.^(-9);      % values of the Resistor and Capacitor
f=(0:60e3); w=2*pi*f;                      % frequency (f) range of measurements
H=(R./(sqrt(R^2+(w*L-(1./(w*C))).^2)));    % Transfer Function

% Magnitude (absolute value) of the transfer function
plot(f,abs(H),'LineWidth',2); grid on; hold on
xlabel('Frequency [Hz]','FontSize',20); ylabel('|H(f)|','FontSize',20)
```

figure

```
plot(f,angle(H)*180/pi,'LineWidth',2); grid on; hold on
xlabel('Frequency [Hz]','FontSize',18); 
ylabel('phase of H(f) [degrees]','FontSize',20)
```

this is the transfer function formula im using
[image]

below is another pic of what my experimental results were and an expected graph, i just dont understand why MATLAB isnt ploting what i want?
[image]

Comment: So you compute H and plot its absolute value versus frequency. What's the question?

Comment: my question is why is it not doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you aware of the [`bodeplot`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/ident/ref/bodeplot.html) function?

The transfer function for a simple second order bandpass is:

[image]

You just need to insert your values into Matlab's `tf` function and plot it with `bodeplot`:

```
R = 55590;
L = 0.9571;
C = 48.811*10.^(-9);

% tf creates transfer function object 
sys = tf( [R*C 0] , [L*C R*C 1]);     % [R*C 0] vector of numerator coeffcients
                                      % R*C*s + 0*1
                                      % [L*C R*C 1] vector of denominator coeff.
                                      % L*C*s^2 + R*C*s + 0*1

bodeplot(sys)                         % plot command to plot frequency response
                                      % of magnitude and phase
```

and it plots:

[image]

Alternatively, if you need more outputs like magnitude and phase as variables, use [`bode`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/ident/ref/bode.html), the plot is equal. But `bodeplot` offers more additional plot customization options.

---

Regarding your comment, that you need a linear axis:

you just need to add the following lines before the plot command:

```
P = bodeoptions;           % handle to plot options
P.MagScale = 'linear';
P.MagUnits = 'abs';
bodeplot(sys,P)            % plot command with custom options
```

so it looks as follows:

[image]

For adjusting the frequency axis limits, use:

```
P.XLim = [1 60e3];
```

or analogue for the magnitude:

```
P.YLim = [0 1];
```

I would advise against a linear frequency axis, but if you REALLY want it, you can use:

```
P.FreqScale = 'linear';
P.FreqUnits = 'Hz';       % optional
```

---

**If you want to plot your experimental data together with the plot above, follow [this example](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Semilog).**

Use `bode` to get equally formatted data from your transfer function, like your experimental data and use `semilogx` to plot it.

```
freqVec = logspace(-1, 3, 5000);
[mag, phs] = bode(sys, freqVec * (2*pi));
mag = db(mag(:));
phs = phs(:);
figure;
subplot(211)
semilogx(freqVec, mag); hold on
semilogx(freqVec, experimentalDataMagnitude); hold off
grid on
title('System Bode Plot')
ylabel('Magnitude (dB)')
subplot(212)
semilogx(freqVec, phs); hold on
semilogx(freqVec, experimentalDataPhase); hold off
grid on
ylabel('Phase (deg)')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
```

Comment: no i wasnt but its not really the thing im after either, i need linear axis because my graphs need to be similar to my experimental data.

Comment: @Theo A linear frequency axis is very uncommon, for a linear magnitude have a look at my edit.

Comment: thank you so much but can you please comment your script as there are a lot of new functions, and where did you input the transfer function equation? or is it part of a predefined function? thanks

Comment: I added some comments, I don't know what else I should comment, actually everything is very clear. Have also a look at the documentary to the particular functions (I already linked some). The example at the bottom just contains some basic functions for plotting of logarithmic data. Should be easy to understand. Please also consider accepting the answer (click the check on left near my question) - as I think it entirely answered your question. Thanks :)

Comment: i think i need to be more specific, i feel bombarded with information and functions, sorry if i  was unclear i meant comment what the function logspace does? is freqvec a variable? what does phs (:) do, is it a standard library function? that sort of thing? thanks:)

Comment: `freqVec` is an logarithmically spaced vector generated by logspace. It is used for the frequency as an example. `mag` and `phs` are the according data vectors for magnitude and phase, generated by the bode function based on `freqVec`. These 3 variables describe the frequency response of your transfer function `sys`. The colon operator `(:)` just makes a column-vector. Your experimental data should also have values for frequency, magnitude and phase. You plot them alltogether with `semilogx` by using `hold on` to keep the plot before.

Comment: can you please explain to me why the x-axis still looks logarithmic? :S

Comment: because you use `semilogx` to plot, thats the idea. ;) Otherwise use `plot`. But seriously, a linear frequency axis is bullshit...

Comment: i dont know why were using a linear axis, ive just been told to do it that way. sorry i feel like i wasnt clear on how crucial the linear axis thing was. have a look at my edit, can you still help?

Comment: I mean I told you before how you get a linear frequency axis, use the `bodeoptions` to set `P.FreqScale = 'linear'` and use the normal `plot` function in any other case.

Comment: i tried the 'linear' thing it didnt seem to work, the graphs turned out nothing like what i was expecting (from the example graph in my edit) it looked like what my original script drew :s

Comment: have you adjusted the axis limits with `P.XLim = [lowerBound upperBound]`?

Comment: yep                        just checked

Comment: I think I can't help you further. I gave you all information you need. You need to check the intermediate results step by step, that will also help you to understand what actually happens.

Comment: -_- my component values were orders of magnitude off what the should have been